# GREP or Regex Search unique characters with a particular series

Tags: linux, unix

I am novice,I want search a huge file using grep or regex which has list of Unique Id's.

Example file:

```
/icon_edit.png\" \/><\/a> AP-28992 : ABCD-1103_01 [v1]","2","2012-10-27 18:40:47","2012-01-04 13:22:41"],
["shawn","extra\/fax","<!-- 0000000000 --><a href=\"javascript:openTCEditWindow(0000,000);\"><img title=\"
TSD\" src=\"gui\/themes\/default\/images\/icon_edit.png\" \/><\/a> AP-28993 : ABCD-1103_02
[v1]","2","2012-10-27 18:40:47","2012-01-04 13:22:41"],
["shawn","extra\/traax","<!-- 0000000000 --> ABCD_110_01
```

Should be filtered uniquely below like:

```
ABCD-1103
ABCD-110
```

Comment: Where did `ABCD-110` come from?

Comment: That's series which is present in the file, I have thousands of such series, which i need to filter out. Like ABCD-110, ABCD-1103,ABCD-1134 so on...

Comment: Do they always start with `ABCD-`? If not, how do you recognise that `AP-28993` shouldn't be printed as well?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess `ABCD-110` is your input pattern and space is delimiter

so if your input file viz. abc.txt is like (i have modified the last line)

```
$cat abc.txt 
/icon_edit.png\" \/><\/a> AP-28992 : ABCD-1103_01 [v1]","2","2012-10-27
18:40:47","2012-01-04 13:22:41"],
["shawn","extra\/fax","<!-- 0000000000 --><a
href=\"javascript:openTCEditWindow(0000,000);\"><img title=\"
TSD\" src=\"gui\/themes\/default\/images\/icon_edit.png\" \/><\/a> AP-28993 :
ABCD-1103_02
[v1]","2","2012-10-27 18:40:47","2012-01-04 13:22:41"],
["shawn","extra\/traax","<!-- 0000000000 --> ABCD-110_01
```

Then the following works:

```
$cat abc.txt  | grep -ow "ABCD-110.*" | awk '{print $1}'
ABCD-1103_01
ABCD-1103_02
ABCD-110_01
```

Comment: It's working for me, only problem is the file which I have is one liner, it failed to filter out everything. I did word wrap and tried still it din't work. But after I searched some unwanted text and replaced it via Notepad++ and saved the text, then ran the command it worked.